# Why is Xcode allocating unnecessary bytes before main function C++?

Tags: c++, memory

I am quite surprised to the see the output when I overloaded the new operator just to track heap allocations. I don't understand why there are so many instead of just 4 for an integer pointer ?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

void* operator new(size_t size) {
    std::cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes. " << std::endl;
    return malloc(size);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Allocating for integer" << std::endl;
    int* a = new int;
}
```

If you scroll to the end there is the 4 bytes But what is the story for allocations before that ? 
I am using GNU 14 and Lib STDc++ also tried with other options like Compiler default and llvm all give the same output

Output:

```
Allocating 104 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 8 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 400 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 8 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 8 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 128 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 128 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 256 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 128 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 128 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 256 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 88 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 88 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 112 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 24 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 96 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 16 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 16 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 208 bytes. 
Allocating 160 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 56 bytes. 
Allocating 112 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 88 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 96 bytes. 
Allocating 40 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 88 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 56 bytes. 
Allocating 56 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 48 bytes. 
Allocating 136 bytes. 
Allocating 136 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 40 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 96 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 80 bytes. 
Allocating 72 bytes. 
Allocating 40 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating 88 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 40 bytes. 
Allocating 32 bytes. 
Allocating 216 bytes. 
Allocating 64 bytes. 
Allocating for integer
Allocating 4 bytes.
```

Comment: You're lucky; those stream inserters are allowed to allocate memory with `operator new`, and if that happens, you'll have an infinite recursion. When you need to trace those operators, use `printf`. It doesn't know about `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I get the same thing even with printf

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I wasn’t clear enough. I wasn’t saying that’s what’s causing the behavior you’re asking about. That’s general advice.

Answer (score 3):

`<iostream>` is rather big. It contains lots of stuff required for io. Just as one example, it contains `std::cout` which is a global object. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout):

> The global objects std::cout and std::wcout control output to a stream buffer of implementation-defined type (derived from std::streambuf), associated with the standard C output stream stdout.
>
> These objects are guaranteed to be initialized during or before the first time an object of type std::ios_base::Init is constructed and are available for use in the constructors and destructors of static objects with ordered initialization (as long as  is included before the object is defined).

Other global objects in `<iostream>` are `std::cin`,`std::wcin`, `std::wcout`, `std::cerr`, `std::wcerr`, `std::clog` and `std::wclog`.

This is nothing particular to XCode. XCode is just an IDE. Other than providing you some comfortable means to invoke the compiler it has nothing to do with compiling your code.

Comment: @NathanS. Xcode is an IDE, it has nothing to do with that

Comment: My point exactly. The title of the question insinuates it's an Xcode thing.

Comment: @NathanS. oh sorry & thanks, now I get it. I missed that it is in the title, because it isnt in the question. I will add a note

Comment: Your justification to me apparently seems like an illusion because the exact code outputs 4 bytes (what we intend) when run through some other IDE

Comment: @TilakMaddy what other IDE? Anyhow then that other IDE is using a different compiler or different implementation of the standard library.

Comment: @TilakMaddy  its like going to a restaurant and getting the food from two different waiters.... what matters is the cook

Comment: @TilakMaddy btw I ascribe your choice of words to the fact that english isnt your first language, otherwise "apparently seems like an illusion" is rather offensive, though nevermind ;)

Comment: ik .I'm sorry I shouldn't have said that - I was a just bit frustrated at my computer. I respect the fact that people like you here take out their valuable time to help others and I'll always be grateful for the help I have received; today was just bad for me dude ~ I apologise again